# Host a server without port forwarding

Tags: http, post

I want to be able to send POST requests from devices outside of my network to my PC.

I am not able to port forward from the router settings page and all of my previous attempts to use UPnP have not worked.

Is there another way that I can send requests to my PC?

Comment: If you have ssh access to a third machine on the external network, you could ssh into it and forward connections to your PC...

Comment: on local netwok you dont need to open port , open port is for remote requests from outside network , check firewal setting first